AWS CloudShell: Timed out
I am attempting to open CloudShell on my AWS account with administrative access, but I keep encountering the following error:
Failed to open session: Timed out while opening the session
I have tried refreshing the browser, deleting the AWS CloudShell home directory, and restarting CloudShell, but none of these solutions have worked.
